# c# CSV FILE How do I delete rows with a date already passed

Tags: c#, csv

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("1.csv"))
     {
         string headerLine = sr.ReadLine();
         String line;
         while (sr.Peek() != -1) // Just read the first line and do nothing with it... 
         while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
         {
             string[] parts = line.Split(',');
             string day = parts[3];
             string month = parts[2];
             string year = parts[1];
             string OldDate = (day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
             DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(OldDate);
             DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;

             if (dt1.Date >= dt2.Date)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show(dt1 + " still relevant ");                       
             }
             else
             {
                 //  How do I delete rows with a date already passed ?
             }
         }
```

Comment: AFAIK you cannot delete a single row from an existing file; you should construct a list in memory which includes "still relevant" lines, then close `streamreader` to free its handle, and finally overwrite it.

Answer (score 2):

You can recreate the text files with the lines you want to keep. Either use your `StreamReader` and fill a `List<string>` or use this LINQ approach:

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadLines("1.csv")
    .Select(l => new{ Line = l, Parts = l.Split(',') })
    .Where(x => x.Parts.Length >= 4)
    .Select(x => new {
        x.Line, 
        Day = x.Parts[3].Trim().TryGetInt32(),
        Month =  x.Parts[2].Trim().TryGetInt32(),
        Year =  x.Parts[1].Trim().TryGetInt32(),
    })
    .Where(x => x.Day.HasValue && x.Month.HasValue && x.Year.HasValue)
    .Select(x => new {x.Line, Date = new DateTime(x.Year.Value, x.Month.Value, x.Day.Value) })
    .Where(x => x.Date >= DateTime.Now)
    .Select(x => x.Line)
    .ToList();

File.WriteAllLines("1.csv", lines);
```

Used this extension method which comes in handy in LINQ queries like this:

```
public static int? TryGetInt32(this string item)
{
    int i;
    bool success = int.TryParse(item, out i);
    return success ? (int?)i : (int?)null;
}
```

Comment: Tim Schmelter,  Thanks, but I got stuck with an error    -   Day = x.Parts[3].Trim().TryGetInt32(),

does not contain a definition for 'GetInt32'

Comment: My file structure is...
(Filename),(end Year),(end Month),( end Day) ,(start Year),(start Month),( start Day) 
lemon.txt,2017,1,29,2017,1,29
Apple.txt,2015,5,21,2017,1,29
orange.txt,2016,3,14,2017,1,29

Comment: @izak: as mentioned at the end of my answer, it's an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) which you have to add to an extension class somewhere in your project.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to keep track of passed date, Here i suggest you to use a `List<DateTime>` Add to the list if it contains the current fetched date. So that Contains is true means the date is already passed. in short you can use like the following:

```
        List<string> linesInFile = File.ReadLines("yourFile.csv").ToList();
        List<DateTime> passedDateList = new List<DateTime>();
        List<string> duplicateLines = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in linesInFile)
        {
            //extract value for date
            string OldDate = (day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
            DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(OldDate);
            if (passedDateList.Contains(dt1))
            {
                duplicateLines.Add(item);
                // the date is already passed
            }
            else
            {
                // it is no yet passed 
                //Do your task here
                passedDateList.Add(dt1);
            }
        }
        linesInFile = linesInFile.Except(duplicateLines).ToList(); // remove already passed line
        File.WriteAllLines("yourFile.csv", linesInFile); // write back to the file
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, my problem is,  if the date is already passed How do I delete the rows